# PHP Converting a badly formed string into a date

Tags: php, date, time

How do I convert the following string:

```
24 May, 2012, 00:00am
```

to a format like:

```
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
```

I've tried the following:

```
$date = date('D M j G:i:s T Y', strtotime("24 May, 2012, 00:00am"));
```

But all I get is:

```
Thu Jan 1 0:00:00 UTC 1970
```

I'm considering exploding the string and then running it through [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and the [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function, which allows you to parse a date according to a format that you define.

In this case:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M, Y, h:ia", "24 May, 2012, 00:00am");
```

You can then use the other DateTime functions to manipulate this.

Note that the date you provide is in fact incorrect by any standard: you either mean `00:00` or `12:00am`.